# Call public function in Main Window from a User Control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, user-controls

I have a Main Window which includes some User Controls that are initialized in the WPF XAML
**MainWindow.xaml**.

```
<Grid>
    <local:RegularUnit x:Name="ucRegularUnit" Grid.Row="0" />
    <local:Actions x:Name="ucActions" Grid.Row="1" />
    // .....
</Grid>
```

I have a public function in the Main Window which I want to call after clicking a Button in my User Control. After searching for some solutions, I found a way to get the parent window instance in my User Control class, but it can't find the function when I'm using `parentWindow.myFunction()`.

User Control `RegularUnit.cs`:

```
public partial class RegularUnit : UserControl
{
    public RegularUnit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_SearchSerialNumber_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        //parentWindow.    //Can't find the function myFunction()
    }
}
```

`MainWindow.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void myFunction()
    {
        // Do Some Stuff...
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't call `myFunction` on `parentWindow` because it's not a member of the standard WPF `Window` class but of your custom `MainWindow`.

What you could do is to cast the result of `Window.GetWindow(this)` to `MainWindow`, like

```
MainWindow parentWindow = (MainWindow)  Window.GetWindow(this);
parentWindow.myFunction();
```

However this is a really bad class design because now your user control depends on being embedded in a specific window.

What you should rather do is to add an event to the user control on which the parent control can subscribe to.

```
public event EventHandler SerialNumberSearch;

private void Button_SearchSerialNumber_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = SerialNumberSearch;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Of course you could use a different kind of EventHandler, depending on what you need.

Comment: Thank you, but nothing works. On the first a "bad" way its still didn't found myFunction() in the parentWindow, and in the second way it gives me an error that its not recognized the "SearialNumberSearch" inside the button_Click function in that line ---->     var handler = SearialNumberSearch;

Comment: @Orionlk Then the code you are using is different from the code you posted or you made a mistake copying my code. The first method *will* show all public members of `MainWindow`. The second is obviously a typing error by me and you should be able to fix that easily.

Comment: I'm still newB in C# and not knowing how to work well with EventHandler

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<YourWindow>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive).YourPublicMethod();
```

Although the above code is a messy way of doing it, but it gets the job done nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on event subscription as suggested by Dirk. I have based event on a simple delegate but you can follow similar pattern and base it on a delegate that suits your scenario.

```
// In UserControl

    namespace TextEditor
    {
        public partial class TextEditorToolBar : UserControl
        {
            // you can use Action type delegate also
            public delegate void getDocumentKeywords(); 
            public event getDocumentKeywords getDocumentRakeKeywordsEvent;

            public TextEditorToolBar()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            // This is event handloer for the button on your user control
            private void ExtractRakeKeywords(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                 var handler = getDocumentRakeKeywordsEvent;

                 if (getDocumentRakeKeywordsEvent != null)
                     getDocumentRakeKeywordsEvent();
            }
        }
    }

// In MainWindow
namespace TextEditor
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DocumentKeywordsExtractor KeyWordsExtractor;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyWordsExtractor = new DocumentKeywordsExtractor(richTextBox);

            // toolbar is the name given to UserControl in MainWindow.xaml
            toolbar.getDocumentRakeKeywordsEvent += ExtractRakeKeywords;

        }

        private void ExtractRakeKeywords()
        {
            KeyWordsExtractor.GetRakeKeywords();
        }
}
```